# How to build an TCP listener or server on google appengine maybe in golang?

Tags: google-app-engine, tcp, go

I'd like to build an TCP receiver/listener/server to run on Google App-Engine.  For example to receive messages over TCP on a specific port, similar to a syslog server, and process the request.  Something in Go language would be ideal, but really anything appengine supports.

Does anyone know if and how I can setup appengine to proccess TCP requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Engine's designed to handle HTTP requests, which are TCP requests.  If you choose to use App Engine, you should probably design your server to handle HTTP requests.

If you need to run on a lower level, you're probably better off using something like Amazon which has tools like their elastic IPs that would make this much easier.

Comment: Looks like its EC2 time.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: you can use GCE or AppEngine Managed VMs now

Answer (score 4):

AppEngine runs your applications in a sandboxed environment and you may not open sockets, as mentioned in their [What Is Google App Engine?](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine) guide:

> As with the Java and Python environments, not all the standard
>   library's functionality is available inside the sandbox. For example,
>   attempts to open a socket or write to a file will return an os.EINVAL
>   error.